# What's the difference if I build an OpenDJ binary myself VS Forgerock Enterprise Released Binary?

Tags: opendj

I'm playing around with Forgerock's LDAP server OpenDJ.

As I know Forgerock Enterprise Binary cannot be used in production without a subscription fee.

I studied the license an learned that if I compile the opensource and build out my own library, it CAN be used in production without any fee to Forgerock.

So, my first question: is this true that it's free to use in production if I build the code myself ?

2nd question is:
What's the real difference between the one I build and the one Forgerock's Enterprise Binary ?  I mean software difference, functional ? performance ? etc

3nd question is:
can the nightly unstable binary be used in production without fee ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) you can.

2) none, major releases are the same. However ForgeRock maintenance releases are only available to customers with a support contract. You'll have to maintain the production source code with the help of the community (which includes ForgeRock employees BTW)

3) yes AFAIK.

I am glad you like OpenDJ :)

Comment: Thanks JnRouvignac.